# verificar tipo de usuario para acesso php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando criar um painel de administrador. Ba tabela do banco já criei o campo tipo, onde se for 1 é usuário normal e 2 administrador. Qual o melhor método para buscar o tipo de usuário no banco?

Segue o codigo que ja fiz porem qualquer tipo de usuario tem acesso ao painel de adm.

```
<body>


    <div class ="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <form action="painel.php" method="POST" >
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="email">E:mail</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email"><br><br>
                        <label for="Senha">Senha:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="**********"><br><br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Entrar</button><p><p><p><p>
                        <input type= "hidden" name="entrar" value="login">


                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"></div>
    </div>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['entrar']) && $_POST['entrar'] == "login"){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $senha = $_POST['senha'];

            if(empty($email) || empty($senha)){
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript"> alert ('preencha todos os campos');
                </script>
                <?php
            }else{
                    $query = "SELECT nome, email, senha, tipo FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha' ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    $busca = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                while($percorrer = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
                        $tipo = $percorrer['tipo'];

                        if($tipo == 2){

                    $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];
                    header('location: painel.php');
                    }


                }
            }

            }


?>

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

EDIT:
no caso o usuario tipo 2 (administrador) esta sendo redirecionado para o login também, estou passando certo o TIPO?

```
$query = "SELECT nome, email, senha, tipo FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha' ";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $busca = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if($busca > 0){
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];
                header('location: painel.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma `$_SESSION['tipo'] = $linha['tipo'];` também no login e nas páginas do painel, no `<header>`, por exemplo, vc verifica o tipo:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['tipo'] != 2){
       // redireciona pra fora do painel, pois não é tipo 2
    }
?>
```

**Atualização:**

Crie uma include (ex. `ver_tipo.php`) e insira antes do `<html>` de cada página do painel:

```
<?php
include_once "ver_tipo.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
...
```

E no arquivo `ver_tipo.php` o script PHP citado no início desta resposta.

Comment: no caso esse codigo fica no login para a area administrativa, eu crio essa session['tipo'] ! = 2 no inicio do painel.php?

Comment: Isso. Coloque antes até do `<head>`, EM CADA UMA das páginas que vc quer restringir acesso. Sugiro criar uma `include` com o código e colocar antes do `<head>`. Com `include`, caso posteriormente vc precisar alterar o código, não terá que modificar página por página do painel.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria desse modo, pois ai ele já estaria verificando se o usuário existe/é ou não administrador. Pois se não existir data em `mysql_fetch_array($result)` automaticamente ele vai reportar que o usuario não existe, se existir e o `tipo == 2` for falso ele reporta que o usuario não existe ou não é administrador. Tem outros modos de fazer claro, mas com o seu código eu consegui pensar nisso apenas.

alert ('preencha todos os campos');
                
                
                         alert ('Usuário não existe/não é administrador');